# Spotty wireless with Fedora

Tags: fedora, wifi

I have this [Toshiba laptop](http://www.officedepot.com/a/products/983671/Toshiba-Satellite-C855-S5194-Laptop-Computer/) I started poking around trying to find out why it quits out so often and is just so bad. [This guy](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/23853/realtek-rtl8192ce-spotty-connection/) seems to have the same problem with the fact that it works perfect in Windows and it cuts out so much. It's quite annoying. Anyone know of any solutions?

Edit* I found that I have to constantly "forget" the network to then re connect to it. This kind of fixes the problem but then of course it derps out again.

Comment: Can you provide some info about your wireless card and version of Fedora? I looked at the link but it's very vague on the details of which chipset the wireless is using. Some `dmesg` output would suffice. I know lots people with Mac's, Win7, and Linux and various hardware that have issues with wireless-N. This can be disabled.

Comment: @slm Fedora 18 and I posted a link because I couldn't find anything better either. Output is here http://freetexthost.com/n6w1v3c10y

Comment: From the link in the comment (it would have been better if you added it to the question) is looks like the router is on a channel that is forbidden for use in the US. Try changing that one.

Comment: Two most common reasons I've met are powersaving issues (bad settings) and temperature. In second case something might be shown in `dmesg` logs. My own wireless card in my laptop restarts itself when temperature on it's sensor rises above 60; that was giving me quite a hard time.

Comment: Thanks for the logs. One thing you might want to try: " modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=1". This will disable wireless-N. You can read more about it in my blog post: http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/6049/debugging-an-intermittently-dropping-intel-wireless-n-1000-network-card-on-fedora-14/. Also can you provide dmesg logs for when the wireless NIC drops out?

Comment: @vonbrand Well that might be a slight bit of a problem. Got any recommendations on how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

That might be a problem with WiFi, not Fedora at all. Check the following:

- Any other WiFi routers around? Check the output of `iwlist wlan0 scan` (assuming your card is wlan0), see if your router is using a crowded channel. If so, look for an unused one (or one with less/worse signal ones) and reconfigure the router
- See if it depends on the position of the machine. Metal does shield the WiFi signal, other materials can absorb the signal; might need to move the router around. Perhaps its antennas aren't in the best position?
- Is there any possible source of electromagnetic interference? Bad fluorescent lighting, perhaps?

Comment: My closest neighbor is corn.... The other points should be as self explanatory.

Comment: Also tested it in multiple other buildings where I am sitting directly under the router.